# DynamoDB return following is not authorized to perform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have endpoint where I post request

`{ "pizza": 1, "address": "Bangladesh", "id": 2 }`

It returns error like this

`{ "errorMessage": "User: arn:aws:sts::676374644948:assumed-role/pizza-api-executor/pizza-api is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:676374644948:table/pizza-order" }`

My IAM policy for DynamoDB:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:Scan",
                "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "dynamodb:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:676374644948:table/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Don't know how to solve this issue

Comment: what is `pizza-api`? You need to attach this policy to `pizza-api`. (Also, you probably should clean up your policy.)

Comment: You say this is the "IAM policy for DynamoDb." I would guess that you need to ensure the role--perhaps the role that is running a lambda--has a policy statement that allows DynamoDb actions.  Most likely you are looking in the wrong spot (wrong user/role).

Comment: @Shawn I am completely new to aws. could u tell me how set this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This walkthrough may help to ensure you have things set up correctly with the permissions on the correct role your lambda is using.  You must create an IAM role and assign that role as the one used by your lambda.  Then you must ensure the role has the correct permissions.

From the [AWS Lambda: Allows a Lambda function to access an Amazon DynamoDB table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_lambda-access-dynamodb.html) example:

> To use this policy, replace the italicized placeholder text in the
> example policy with your own information. Then, follow the directions
> in create a policy or edit a policy.
>
> To use this policy, attach the policy to a Lambda service role. A
> service role is a role that you create in your account to allow a
> service to perform actions on your behalf. That service role must
> include AWS Lambda as the principal in the trust policy. For details
> about how to use this policy, see [How to Create an AWS IAM Policy to
> Grant AWS Lambda Access to an Amazon DynamoDB Table](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-create-an-aws-iam-policy-to-grant-aws-lambda-access-to-an-amazon-dynamodb-table/) in the AWS
> Security Blog.

That last link will be the most useful because it walks through the entire process and shows screenshots of all the steps.